# Windows Terminal - npm is not responding

Tags: npm, git-bash, windows-terminal

When using the specific *combination* of Git Bash and Windows Terminal, `npm` does not do anything.  For example, `npm -v`, `npm install`, or any other command starting with `npm` will just go to the next line with no response.

However, when I run `npm -v` or `npm` in general on other terminals on my Windows 10 PC, it works fine.

It also works fine in Windows Terminal when using:

- Git Bash itself
- PowerShell
- CMD

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling a bunch of times to no avail, and I don't believe `npm` itself is installed incorrectly since it works fine with Command Prompt.

Edit: Windows Terminal settings for Git Bash:

```
{
 "guid": "{ed985d27-ac7c-477b-a3fc-1f59152f5199}",
 "commandline": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
 "cursorShape": "filledBox",
 "icon": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
 "name": "Git Bash",
 "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%",
 "tabTitle": "Git Bash"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What is your current Windows Terminal profile for Git Bash?  Go to Windows Terminal Settings and click *"Open JSON file"* at the bottom left of the settings screen.  Find the Git Bash section under *"profiles"* and add everything between the brackets to your question, if you would.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that Windows Terminal may be running Git Bash without picking up part of your startup config, such as `~/.bashrc` or ~/.bash_profile`.  Git Bash seems to have a slightly different idea of how these should be sourced than "regular Bash", and I'm much more familiar with the normal Linux version.

You mentioned "reinstalling a bunch of times", but my assumption is that you meant Windows Terminal.

I only have about a 25% confidence that this will fix it, but what I'd like for you to try is deleting your `Git Bash` profile in Windows Terminal, downloading the latest Git Bash, and reinstalling.

The reason for this is that the latest Git Bash includes a JSON fragment extension for Windows Terminal that will create a profile automatically.  From the looks of your current profile, I don't believe it was created by Git Bash.  The newly installed one should force the shell to launch as a login, interactive shell (`-l -i`) to make sure that all necessary files are sourced.

You could also try just editing the profile to add `-l -i` to the `bash.exe`:

```
{
 "guid": "{ed985d27-ac7c-477b-a3fc-1f59152f5199}",
 "commandline": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe -l -i",
 "cursorShape": "filledBox",
 "icon": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
 "name": "Git Bash",
 "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%",
 "tabTitle": "Git Bash"
}
```

But I'd just try the reinstall of the latest Git Bash, which should set it up automatically.

If this doesn't change anything, some additional things to try:

- Run `which npm` in Git Bash both with and without Windows Terminal.  Are the results the same or different?
- Try starting PowerShell in Windows Terminal, then manually run `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe`.  Does `npm` work?  If not, try `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe -l -i` to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try to reinstall windows terminal.

Comment: The OP mentioned that has already been done "a bunch of times".